# Unknown brazed steel frame

Tags: frames, steel

Hi all new here after a lot of searching, i was hoping maybe someone would be able to help me. Ive been trying to find out what frame i have. I bought a old steel frame from a car boot sale about 10 year ago, it had been painted badly with alot of rust. I have no idea why i got the frame but fancied a challenge project. Stripped it back and cleaned it up best i could, and found no identifying numbers or marks other than suntour on the dropouts and the one in the picture[image: Stamp]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]

Comment: Zooming out, I can read "Mod. Gipiemme", however I do not understand what I am seeing, please give a photo of the whole bike.

Comment: Suntour dropouts, usually indicate a Japanese made frame. That style of brake usually indicates a city/crossover type bike. A kickstand mount puts the frame somewhere in the middle lower end for it's price range. Bridgestone had some frames similar to this in the XO line but I didn't find a match. Often frames like this had brazed on rack mounts - this one does not.

Comment: What size seatpost does it take? That is often an indicator of tubing quality. The combination of double eyelets on the rear dropouts but no eyelets on the upper seat stays for rack mounting is weird (unless I’m missing the mounts). And seat stay is also an unusual place for a pump peg. Altogether says custom touring bike to me.

Comment: No matter what answers people come up with, that is a good-looking bike and is totally a candidate for a build.  If it is suitably-sized for you then go ahead and make it your own, or do it up for a loved-one.    Looks like a fun project, do a good prep, then paint and assembly.

Comment: Serial number? Can you add detail that makes it clearer how the various joints that at least don't look brazed were done? The TT to sleeve, DT-BB, and ST-BB all look like either welded or internally lugged. The combination of kickstand plate with so much hand finishing and no domed chainstays all scream small builder to me, plus the sleeve, fillet fastback, and fillet chainstays are all labor intensive and basically never on production bikes and especially not production bikes with kickstand plates.

Comment: No serial numbers on the frame that i can see, the seat post diameter is 25.20mm. other than the brazing there doesn't appear to be any visible welding. The frame is a perfect ride very comfortable size. And no eyelets on the upper seat stays, guess i will never know the true identity of the frame. Not that it matters its a nice frame to ride just thought i could add some brand stickers to the finish. thank you all for your help. learnt more than i did on my own

Comment: @Ady No serial number plus ST sleeve plus all the fillet basically cements it as a small framebuilder. Production ST sleeve bikes exist but are rare, and they're fairly common in the framebuilder world.

Answer (score 2):

The First photo shows a Gipiemme brake bridge. This part, like the SunTour dropouts, has been selected by the frame builder but doesn't really help to identify the builder.

the tubing on the main frame has been brazed in an unusual style most often associated with Peugeot. The frame is probably not a Peugeot.

Most likely it is from a small volume custom framebuilder or possibly even a decent home or work project. Ultimately it is very unlikely that you will determine the true origin.